# How to get php array data with jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get an array of data from my php function using ajax but having a difficult time. Here is my php function:

```
function dallas_db_facebook_make_post () {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_dallas_facebook WHERE time > NOW() ORDER BY time LIMIT 1";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

    foreach($results as $result) {
        $fbposttext = $result['text'];
        $fbposttime = $result['time'];
        $array = array('post' => $fbposttext, 'posttime' => $fbposttime);
        echo json_encode($array);

    }   

}
```

Here is my jQuery function:

```
function send_fb_post() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: my_ajax.ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'action': 'dallas_db_facebook_make_post'

        },
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        success: function(data){
            var jq_json_obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(jq_json_obj);

        },
        error: function(){
        },
    });
};
```

Comment: Are you sending data to a php function and expecting data in the form of an array back or do you want to sent an array to the php side?

Comment: I am trying to get the data from the php function in the form of an array to use in my jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

Some correction, you need to output the total array when for loop completes. below function will work i think

```
function dallas_db_facebook_make_post () {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_dallas_facebook WHERE time > NOW() ORDER BY time LIMIT 1";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

    foreach($results as $result) {
        $fbposttext = $result['text'];
        $fbposttime = $result['time'];
        $array[] = array('post' => $fbposttext, 'posttime' => $fbposttime);
    }
        echo json_encode($array);   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function dallas_db_facebook_make_post () {
    global $wpdb;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM wp_dallas_facebook WHERE time > NOW() ORDER BY time LIMIT 1";
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);

    foreach($results as $result) {
        $fbposttext = $result['text'];
        $fbposttime = $result['time'];
        $array[] = array('post' => $fbposttext, 'posttime' => $fbposttime);
    }
        echo json_encode($array);   

}
```

Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "your url",
       dataType: "json",
       data: {action: 'dallas_db_facebook_make_post'},
       success: function(response) {
           console.log(response);
       }
});
```

And check what you are seeing in the console. If you are using chrome as browser, right click and click on inspect element. There are you seeing the console.

I think you can get the element like: response[index]['post'];

Comment: Nothing is being returned in the console. If I do something like 'error: function(error){ console.log(error)}' then it looks like the array shows up in the console.

Comment: Okay, and what is the request saying in chrome under the network tab? Can you post a screenshot from that?

Comment: I can take a screenshot but it's just saying Form Data action: dallas_db_facebook_make_post

Comment: It's not showing any actual data being sent under the "Form Data" section

Comment: Check the response tab.

Comment: That's showing [{"post":"asdf","posttime":"2016-07-13 00:00:00"}]0 which is the correct data.

Comment: Nice! Now you can do this in your succes: console.log(response.post); I hope that asdf is returned at the console.

Comment: Ugh..no it wasn't returned. Nothing was.

Comment: You are saying that the response tab is showing  [{"post":"asdf","posttime":"2016-07-13 00:00:00"}] ?

Comment: That is the good response what is at the response variable in the succes.

Comment: Is this what you are asking for? success: function(response){ console.log(response.post); }

Comment: Yes, and if that isn't working:  success: function(response){ console.log(response) } and show me the output in the console.

Comment: There's actually nothing being returned in success. I can do alert("success") and nothing happens.

Comment: It isn't going in the succes function?